# Bug when Task.Factory.FromAsync is calling C# base methods in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, async-await

I'm using the latest version of `Xamarin.iOS` (8.10.5.26). While developing a cross-platform library which heavily uses async/await methods, I found that it works fine with Android, Mono, Microsoft CLR but it crashes on iOS. Narrowing the issue down has lead to what I suspect to be a bug in CLR implementation on iOS.

If you have a class `MyNetworkStream` derived from `NetworkStream` which overrides its methods, iOS version may call `MyNetworkStream's` `EndRead` when the caller assumes that `base.EndRead` should be called. This happens in this scenario:

```
int bytesRead = await Task.Factory.FromAsync<int>(base.BeginRead(buffer, 0, count, null, null), base.EndRead);
```

All other platforms but iOS call `base.EndRead` (`NetworkStream.EndRead`). Is it indeed a bug in iOS version of CLR or am I missing something?

**The entire sample:**

```
public class MyNetworkStream : NetworkStream
{
    public MyNetworkStream(Socket sock) : base(sock)
    {
    }

    public override IAsyncResult BeginRead(byte[] buffer, int offset, int size, AsyncCallback callback, object state)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("BeginRead ERROR");
        return base.BeginRead(buffer, offset, size, callback, state);
    }

    public override int EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
    {
        int x = 0;
        throw new InvalidOperationException("EndRead ERROR");
        return base.EndRead(asyncResult);
    }

    public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Read ERROR");
        return base.Read(buffer, offset, count);
    }

    public override async Task<int> ReadAsync(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        int bytesRead = await Task.Factory.FromAsync<int>(base.BeginRead(buffer, 0, count, null, null), base.EndRead);
        return bytesRead;
    }
}


// Put this in a button click handler or something like that.
using (TcpClient client = new TcpClient("mail.afterlogic.com", 143))
{
    MyNetworkStream mns = new MyNetworkStream(client.Client);
    byte[] b = new byte[1024];
    await mns.ReadAsync(b, 0, b.Length);
}
```

iOS version causes `InvalidOperationException` with "EndRead ERROR" message, other versions don't as they never get into `MyNetworkStream.EndRead` (or any `MyNetworkStream` methods at all). Interestingly that `base.BeginRead` is OK, only `base.EndRead` is a problem. I.e. `Task.Factory.FromAsync` picks the correct value for Begin method but not for End counterpart (as the first one is just `IAsyncResult` while second one is Func). So the problem is with Func, I suppose.

Comment: Very simple workaround seems to be this:    'Func<IAsyncResult, int> f = base.EndRead; int bytesRead = await Task.Factory.FromAsync<int>(base.BeginRead(buffer, 0, count, null, null), f);'. This works. However, the question why the original form doesn't work remains.

Comment: I think you should submit a bug report